# Two colored circle in React Native without svg or similar (using Views)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

is it possible to create a two colored circle in react-native without svg? I made a quick mockup in paint.net so you can see what I exactly want.

[image: two-colored circle mockup]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```js
<View style={{
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
      borderRadius: 100,
      overflow: 'hidden'
    }}>
      <View style={{
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        height: 100,
        width: 200
      }} />
      <View style={{
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        height: 100,
        width: 200
      }} />
    </View>
```